# Magento : Home Page not Properly Showing

Tags: magento, block

I am having a problem in my magento site. I tried to create static block for show slider in right side-bar and set it in widgets. Now when I refresh my website home page looking like that....

I deleted that static blocks and refreshed but home page was same...

pls give me ur reformative suggestion and am a beginner level magento user...
[image]

Comment: you need to just do caching and indexing from admin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?